# React state is not updating, trying to use ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

Why is the state not updating? I have checked that i receive data from the api in the correct form. I can print the result if i change it instead of trying to add it to a new array and put it in the state. I have also checked that this exists in the scope and as I understand it should work since I am using an arrow function. I still receive an empty array after the map function.

What am I missing?

```
class CurrencyForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currencies: [],
  }
  componentDidMount(){
   this.fetchCurrencies();
  }

  fetchCurrencies = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('some address')
    response.data.map(currency => 
    this.setState({currencies: [...this.state.currencies,currency.id]}
    ))
   }
```

Comment: Aren't you suppose to do something like `this.setState({ currencies: response.data });` ? Your code doesn't seem right as you are mapping each of your response data element and calling `setState`

Comment: maybe this is a bad solution, but the data I receive is in the form of multiple JSON objects and I am only interested to display one value from an object.

Comment: @DanielDunér check my answer you could reduce your code to one setstate call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `[...this.state.currencies, currency.id]`.

Since `setState` is also async, the state does not change for each iteration of the map. So you are always using the same `this.state.currencies`. This means that you should only get the last `currency.id` added.

You should either use the function version of `setState`

```
this.setState((state) => ({currencies: [...state.currencies,currency.id]}));
```

or simply do the `map` and use the resulting array to set the state

```
fetchCurrencies = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('some address');
    const currencyIds = response.data.map(currency=>currency.id);
    this.setState({currencies: [...this.state.currencies,...currencyIds]}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the problem with what I did. This solved it for me.

Comment: oh yeah. this reminds me, among other reasons, why I switched to vue.js.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to put all the id's in the state.. instead of calling `setState` so many times, You could put all the ids in an array first then update the state with that array something like this:

```
fetchCurrencies = async () => {
const response = await axios.get('some address')
const idsArray = response.data.map(currency => currency.id)
this.setState({currencies: idsArray})
}
```

and remember setState is an async call so you may not be able to see the result if you put `console.log`  just after `setState` instead try console logging in your render method

Comment: `map` function returns an array, if you were to use `push`, I'll suggest you to use `forEach` instead. @Gabriele's answer has the correct way of doing it.

Comment: yeah we could directly use assign as well.. probably thats better way of doing it i will edit now